# What to do about the speaking tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, burninate-request

The [speaking](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking) tag has six questions.

- Three of those questions only need the [conversations](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversations) tag:

  - [How can I get Americans to speak more slowly after I've already asked them once?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/how-can-i-get-americans-to-speak-more-slowly-after-ive-already-asked-them-once)
  - [How to respond to someone when they ask how much you earn?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/how-to-respond-to-someone-when-they-ask-how-much-you-earn)
  - [How can I politely ask someone to get off their phone?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/how-can-i-politely-ask-someone-to-get-off-their-phone)
- One of the questions needs a not-yet-created [public-speaking](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-speaking) or [presentations](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentations) tag.
- The remaining don't have any special information communicated by the [speaking](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking) tag.

What should we do about the tag?

Comment: Interesting. I shoulda seen this one before I added some speaking tags today.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old but still valid question and I would say: let's delete it!

This tag as no definition and people tend to use it as the opposite of [non-verbal-communication](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-verbal-communication) which almost every question here. Knowing this, I believe that this tag doesn't add value to any question and should, therefore, be removed.